# can memory address be stored in an integer type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can we store a memory address in integer type for example if I do this then I get an error:

```
int i;
int j = &i;
```

I know we can do that by using pointers like `int* j = &i` but I want to know if there is any other ways to store the address without using a pointer. Please let me know if there is anyway I can do this with an `int` type.

Comment: [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) in c++: "Any pointer can be converted to any integral type large enough to hold the value of the pointer (e.g. to std::uintptr_t)."

Answer (score 2):

When storing an address in an int, it is likely that part of the address is going to be truncated.  I'm not sure exactly why you would need to store an address as an int, but if you really need to, use std::intptr_t. It is large enough to hold an address.

Comment: `std::intptr_t` or `std::uintptr_t`. Ones without `std` are likely to be from C headers. Not likely to be a big deal, but you should use C++ in C++.